# How can I Unassigned all products from categories in Multi-Store

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, multi-website

Don't want to delete products, because i just assigned my products to my next store like adding another root category and assigned to categories, Same products assigned to two stores. How can i bulk Unassigned products from second store categories?

Comment: Are you know about Update attributes action in admin side under products grid? See here https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-update-attribute-sets-in-bulk.html

Comment: Export the all-products CSV from Magento; Open with a Spreadsheet editor. Filter out the Store view you wish to delete. Save as `.csv` with the Filtered rows - Re-import with the Delete Command - if you're wanting to do this via the UI?

Comment: @Abdul my site consists 20k products, so not possible what you suggest if i try that my server getting down. So how can i do it by DB or CSV?

Comment: @MackieeE can i get exact csv, my workout: website, sku delete entities-> it should be deleted both website

Comment: @zus If you trying limited products (5k) then same issue?

Comment: @Abdul can i get csv format?

Comment: @Abdul and what is my import behavior?

Comment: @zus Check here vendor\magento\module-import-export\Files\Sample

Comment: My magento ver 1.9.2.3

Comment: Is my csv format correct : https://snag.gy/PEdblx.jpg, and import behavior https://snag.gy/JmvPo2.jpg is delete entities. Is right my workout...

Answer (score 0):

If you are a developer, you can try below code.

**IMPORTANT: You should try this on a test environment with backup first as I haven't tested this code**

To run this, create a php file in **shell** directory in magento root and save below code.

```
<?php

require_once 'abstract.php';

class Mage_Shell_ProductSave extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{

    public function run()
    {
        //Change this before you run
        $websiteIdToRemoveProducts = 1;
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
        $tableName = $resource->getTable('catalog/product_website');

        $query = "DELETE FROM `{{$tableName}` WHERE `website_id` = {$websiteIdToRemoveProducts}";
        $writeConnection->query($query);
    }

}

$shell = new Mage_Shell_ProductSave();
$shell->run();
```

**Change the** `$websiteIdToRemoveProducts` **value before your run**. 
Once you saved the code, run:

```
php yourFilename.php
```

From command line

After that run below command from the same path:

```
php indexer.php --reindexall
```

Then Flush your cache.

Comment: Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'abstract.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\abc\mu.php on line

Comment: https://justpaste.it/1f99g   correct me.

Comment: put your file in "shell" directory and then run

Comment: @zus did that work for you?

Comment: In my case,  Don't want to delete products, because i just assigned my products to my next store like adding another root category and assigned to categories,   Same products assigned to two stores. How can i bulk Unassiged products from second store categories?

Comment: Update your question

Comment: check with my updated question.

Comment: How can i do it by Bulk Update, I tried a lot of combination, still not working.

Comment: My answer is not to delete your products. It will just remove it from one website and the other one will be there

Comment: Code: https://justpaste.it/1g1nb error: https://snag.gy/0HPdci.jpg How can i solve this.

Comment: Read my answer carefully and make sure you pasted the file in the correct directory. Also if you are following my steps, you will need to run it in command line